# A strange finding with the logrank test statistics

Tags: variance, type-i-and-ii-errors, logrank-test

When I try to confirm the type I error rate of the logrank test by simulation, I found something strange...
Firstly, I generated 100 observations from exponential distribution with lamda1=1 as group 1 and another 100 observations from the same distribution as group 2. No censoring. Repeating this for 1000 times and using survdiff in R I got 1000 logrank test statistics (O-E)/sqrt(V). About 50 out of the 1000 tests had p value < 0.05. So everything is good and there is no surprise.

However, in my 2nd simulation I generated 80 observations from exponential distribution with lamda1=1 and 20 observations from exponential distribution with lamda2=10 as group 1 (a mix of 2 different exponentials), and same for group 2. Again no censoring. The type I error is surprisingly only about 1%, way below the 5% level. I believe the reason is that the variance from the logrank test statistics (i.e. the V in (O-E)/sqrt(V)) is about 49, which overestimates the true variance of (O-E), which seems to be about 25 based on the 1000 simulated values.

Do you have any insights why this is happening? The logrank test is non-paramatric so I wasn't expecting such a tweak in the underlying distribution will result in such a big impact on the type I error. What should be the correct variance estimator for O-E in such a situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved. The way of generating the data is causing the problem. If instead we generate a random variable with 80% chance of being 1 and 20% chance of being 0 and if =1 generate from exponential with lamda1 and if = 0 then generate from exponential with lamda2, this problem is no longer there.